# Weird black 'outer border' outside border in IE11

Tags: css, border, stylesheet

I've been creating a Leaflet map with Icons. The icons all have a 1 pixel white border around them. That works fine, but in IE11 there is some weird, very small, black line outside of the border.

[image]

I've been looking around for explanation, but couldn't find anything about it online. Does anyone have a idea what could cause this outer 'line'?

Below the CSS I used on the `div` element.

```
.lfpt-icon-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: rgb(66, 20, 95);
}
```

Here the HTML of the icon wrapper

```
<div class="lfpt-icon-wrapper" aria-label="5G Fieldlab icoon" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
  <span class="lfpt-icon g-fieldlab"></span>
</div>
```

The image in the cirlce is a dynamically set base64 background image on the inside `span` element.

Hope someone can help me further!

Comment: Hey Camille, can you also provide your HTML code

Comment: Hey @RémyTesta I've added the HTML of the icon element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a old bug in IE11 with the `border-radius`.

Try adding this line to your class:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

If you encounter weird edges or that the circle is not quite round you could try also adding this line:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Please mark my post as the correct answer if it helped you! Thanks! :)

Answer (score -2):

remove border and make it as 0.
border: 0;

Comment: I do need the border, so disabling doesn't do the fix. I just want it to work in IE11 the same way as in Chrome